# Leer cualquier archivo extension .txt dentro de una carpeta especifica en ruby cada 2 minutos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

quiero leer cada 2 minutos todos los archivos uno por uno de una carpeta ejemplo C:\folder\ todos los que tienen una extensión txt. pero no se los nombres de cada archivo ya que son aleatorios. luego de leer seria conveniente eliminarlos para evitar sobre carga..

alguien tendra una idea de como se podria hacer?

Comment: que vas a ser con la informacion despues de leer los archivos la guardas en una base de datos ?

Comment: si exactamente.. primero leo luego interpreto ya que estan  encriptadas y luego guardo...

Comment: te recomiendo q leas sobre los task en rails son tareas programadas y si serai bueno ir eliminando los archivos una vez sean leidos eso lo puedes manejar con un estado 1 es leido 0 no leido algo asi

Comment: gracias oscar y tendras alguna linea que lea cualquier archivo?

Comment: No tengo uno pero puedes leer sobre la clase File de ruby https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa Dir#[] para obtener el array de archivos y con ellos hace lo que quieras:

```
Dir['C:\folder\*.txt'].each do |file|
  # Lo que quieras hacer
  # por ejemplo SecretObject.new(File.read(file)).save
  File.rm(file)
end
```

Para que ese proceso se repita cada dos minutos podes usar `sleep` y `loop`:

```
loop do
  # procesar_archivos()
  sleep 120
end
```

Comment: Thanks... is the mores simple way....